# Sublime Text 3 - How do I delete a file from the remote server?

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp, remote-server

I have SFTP installed. I've been Googling this. How do I delete a file, not a folder, from the remote server via Sublime Text 3?

This doesn't tell me anything:

Delete Remote File

Context menu only

Delete the file off of the server

---

Because I'm not seeing anything in the contextual menu about deleting a file, just a folder.

Comment: Select `SFTP: Browse Server` in the command palette, select the server, and navigate to the file you want to delete. When you select it, you get asked what you want to do with it, and you can select `Delete` from the list.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Why would I know this belongs in Super User? Not being snarky. Super User to ask how to delete a file from the server via Sublime?? 

And OdatNurd, actually, "Delete" was not an option when I browsed the server. I had no options. Just the file sitting there. Which is why I asked. Thanks!